# How to check if first XML node exist?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

I have the following XML:

```
<Root><Node1>node1 value</Node1><Node2>node2 value</Node2></Root>
```

I'd like to check if `Root` is the first node. If so, I then want to get the values for the to child nodes.

This XML is inside of an XElement. I've tried this:

```
xml.Element("Root")
```

but that returns null. If Root exist, shouldn't it return a non null value?

Comment: What is `xml`?  What type?

Comment: How about defining an XML schema and validating your XML document?

Answer (score 0):

```
        string xml = @"<Root><Node1>node1 value</Node1><Node2>node2 value</Node2></Root>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var root = doc.Root;
        if(root.Name == "Root")
        {
            foreach(var el in root.Descendants())
            {
               string nodeValue = el.Value;
            }

        }
```

You can check the name of the Root element from `Root.Name`. After that loop all elements in the root using `doc.Root.Descendants()`.

Comment: My XML is in an XElement. Are you saying I'll need to put it into an XDocument?

Comment: @4thSpace I don't know your exact case. But if this is the whole xml document you should put it in XDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Since `xml` is an instance of `XElement`, it already references the root element, which in this case named `Root`. Doing `xml.Element("Root")` will return result only if the `<Root>` element has another child `<Root>`.

> *I'd like to check if `Root` is the first node.*

You can simply check the `Name` of the root element :

```
var raw = "<Root><Node1>node1 value</Node1><Node2>node2 value</Node2></Root>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(raw);
if (xml.Name.ToString() == "Root")
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
else 
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Root><Node1>node1value</Node1><Node2>node2value</Node2></Root>");
        if(doc!=null)
        {
            if (doc.Root.Name.LocalName == "Root")
            {
                foreach (var i in doc.Descendants())
                   Console.WriteLine(i.Value);
            }
        }
```